# HTTP Error 400 using Ansibles URI Module with gitlab api

Tags: api, ansible, gitlab, uri

I'm trying to commit to a gitlab project using [ansibles uri module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/uri_module.html)
and the [gitlab api](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html).

The final goal is to move the JSON into a template and commit information from multiple machines to different files in the gitlab project.

But for now i am stuck using the uri module propperly.

I was able to commit using the gitlab api and curl on the ansible linux box.

```
PAYLOAD=$(cat << 'JSON'
{
  "branch": "master",
  "commit_message": "some commit message",
  "actions": [
    {
      "action": "create",
      "file_path": "Leer/test",
      "content": "some content"
    }
]
}
JSON
)
```

```
curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data "$PAYLOAD" http://gitlab/api/v4/projects/2/repository/commits
```

And translated it into the following ansible role git-commit:

```
- name: commit to gitlab
  uri:
    url: http://gitlab/api/v4/projects/2/repository/commits
    method: POST
    body_format: json
    headers:
      PRIVATE-TOKEN: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    body: |
      '{
        "branch": "master",
        "commit_message": "some ansible commit message",
        "actions": [
         {
           "action": "create",
           "file_path": "Leer/test2",
           "content": "some new content"
         }
        ]
      }'
```

Used the role in the Playbook git.yml:

```
---
- hosts: 10.101.127.116
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  become: true
  roles:
  - git-commit
```

And run the Playbook:

```
ansible-playbook -k git.yml
```

But I receive the following http error 400:

```
fatal: [10.101.127.116]: FAILED! => 
{
"changed": false,
"connection": "close",
"content": "", 
"content_length": "0", 
"content_type": "text/html; charset=utf-8", "date": 
"Thu, 18 Apr 2019 13:11:13 GMT", 
"msg": "Status code was 400 and not [200]: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request", "redirected": false, 
"server": "nginx", 
"status": 400, 
"url": "http://gitlab/api/v4/projects/2/repository/commits", 
"x_request_id": "WNfjPOBkVk5", "x_runtime": "0.002530"
}
```

I appreciate any kind of help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incorrectly using YAML quoting:

```
   body: |
      '{
```

Means the `body` is literally the single quote character and then an open brace, because the yaml `|` character is, itself, a quoting construct.

You can either remove both of the single quotes (the single quote character is not legal in JSON), or you can remove the pipe and then move the single quote up to the `body:` level

You may find the use of a YAML to JSON conversion tool helpful in seeing what the document would look like; there are several online, and [remarshal](https://github.com/dbohdan/remarshal#readme) which runs on your computer